# Changing scope variable on ng-click without calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, operators, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

How can I change a Scope Variable without calling a function from controller.

I'm trying to show a div content when the editState variable equals to 1 but it's not working.

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-controller="profileCtrl as pctrl">

    <div data-ng-click="pctrl.editState === 1">Edit</div>

    <div data-ng-if="pctrl.editState === 1">
        .....
    </div>

</body>
```

**JS**(in profileCtrl controller)

```
this.editState = 0;
```

But when I called a function it's working (I don't want to do this way)

```
<div data-ng-click="pctrl.editFn()">Edit</div>

this.editFn = function() {
     this.editState = 1;
}
```

Comment: Typo change `===` to `=` @ `data-ng-click="pctrl.editState === 1"` to `data-ng-click="pctrl.editState = 1"`. You need assignment operator (`=`) not comparison operator (`===`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While setting value inside `ng-click` directive, use assignment operator `=` instead of `===` exact check operator.

It should be

```
<div data-ng-click="pctrl.editState = 1">Edit</div>
```

Instead of

```
<div data-ng-click="pctrl.editState === 1">Edit</div>
```